# Excel not accessible after import of data through script

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007, python

I am using a python script to open up an excel workbook (by creating a pointer to it). After I put some data in the excel and script execution is completed, I tried to access(see note below ) the excel. But its not accessible. To get access to it, you have to open some other excel and then you can modify this excel. Can anyone please tell how to access this excel after import without going to another excel and then coming back to this one? 
Note: Access means when you click on that excel from Taskbar (the strip at bottom of desktop having start button and other buttons), it shows up on desktop. But when you click at any place in excel, no cell is selected.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't really given much to go on.

I'm assuming that you are using a Python library to access the workbook?

So, to clarify, You are using Python to open a workbook and insert some data?

If so, are you releasing it or closing it after the script executes? That is the most likely issue.

Comment: Ya, I know that. I searched on google but unable to find how to release that. Can you please tell the solution or some other hint?

Comment: What library are you using? Is what I wrote in the 3rd paragraph accurate? Can you share some code because there really isn't enough to go on in your question.

Comment: I am using `xlrd`. And what you said in 3rd para is also correct.

Comment: OK, I've not used that library, most of my external Excel was done in PHP, not done any for a while. Can you post some code somewhere - I'm happy to take a look.